# jQuery list: how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with cells in it where the user can click **once**. This works pretty well.

My code looks like this: to summarize: when the user clicks on a cell, I fadeout **all** cells that have a special property `data-to-shoot` (and there's always only one cell like that):

```
td.css({
    'cursor': 'pointer'
})
.click(function() {
    var c = self.getShoot(undefined); /* undefined = no shoot */
    $('table#user td[data-to-shoot=1]').each(function() {
        var fadeIn  = $(this).data('fade-in');
        $(this)
            .removeAttr('data-to-shoot')
            .html(c)
            .stop()
            .data('fading', true)
            .animate({
                backgroundColor: fadeIn
            }, 1000, function() {
                $(this)
                    .data('fading', false)
                    .hover(
                        self.hoverOnlyEmptyCellsIn,
                        self.hoverOnlyEmptyCellsOut
                    );
            });
    });
```

Now I want to give the user the possibility to click many times (pre-defined variable) in a FIFO fashion: for example if he's allowed to "select" 3 cells, he may click 3 times and the 4th time, I want the first cell to fadeOut and the new one to fadeIn.

How to implement this? What is the big idea?

Comment: LIFO? I think you mean FIFO

Comment: @miguel-svq +1 for you, corrected.

Comment: Quite obvious: FIFO buffer. A simple global variable (array), push the new one + if length>maxlength slice the first one and "reactivate" it

Comment: May I ask you to answer so I can check it as valid then?

Comment: Give a custom counter data to clicked tds and check the td count that has that data every time. If the count of tds that has that data is 3 means the td has that data equal to 1 should be removed, 2 should be 1, 3 should be 2 and the new clicked one will be 3

Comment: My main problem is that I have to *rotate* them, i.e. for 3 items to click, eliminate the first then second becomes first, third becomes second and clicked becomes third...

Comment: @Olivier  I understand what Batu Zet means. Is the same concept, but you are using teh elements themselves to store the data (a la array). This could have the advantage that you can easily select them to deactivate (& remove the data- attribute) or to increase the data attribute itself. Its a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the elements clicked in a variable and then shift the first in element off the array when the max number of allowable clicked elements have been selected, like so:

```
var MAX_SELECTIONS = 3;
var selectedArray = new Array();

$('.cell').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        selectedArray.push($(this));
        if(selectedArray.length > MAX_SELECTIONS){
            selectedArray[0].removeClass('selected');
            selectedArray.shift();
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/DNLY8/

Comment: After reading Miguel's answer after submitting mine, I realized that I originally left out an important piece of logic.. Making sure a previously selected cell was not re-added to the array. Code and link updated..

Answer (score 1):

Quite obvious: FIFO buffer, you knew the solution.

A simple implementation could be like:

- Define simple global variable (array)
- on each user activation (click on no active cell)

  - push the new selected element (a reference to it?) to the array
  - "deactivate" the element
  - if length>maxlength

    - slice the first element
    - "reactivate" the sliced element.

...and if you want user to deactivate at will just need to add

- on each user deactivation (click on active cell)

  - slice the clicked element
  - "reactivate" the sliced element.